# Exporting CSV containing startURL

Tags: scrapy

I have a couple of problems scraping images and exporting the results as a CSV with Scrapy. My settings are:

```
FEED_URI = 'export.csv'
FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'
```

The first problem is that the export comes out as JSON, not CSV. The other issue is that I would like the export to include the start_urls, so the export should be:

```
start_url, original_image, scraped_image
http://www.bk.com, http://www.bk.com/images/bk-logo-rv.png, http://mysite.com/53948534985374.jpg
```

That's the command I am running:

```
scrapy crawl image_downloader -L ERROR --logfile=log
```

And that's the pipeline:

```
class ImageDownloaderPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        return item
```

Could anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: what commands you are using to run the spider ?  is there any other custom pipeline you have already implemented in code ?

Comment: I have updated the description with the command and the pipeline. Thanks for your help!